# What function/syscall is used by iOS to read and write files

Tags: objective-c, ios, swizzling

I want to intercept file read/write on iOS for providing transparent encryption/decryption functionality to some of my apps.

I know I can swizzle the various SDK methods for reading/writing files to do this, but that entails a LOT of hard work and is prone to error (I may miss swizzling some method, causing my application to crash/misbehave).

If there is some common syscall/function used by all these methods, then I'd rather swizzle it and save on some hard work + make it more foolproof. Is there any such common entry point?

PS: Acceptance into the app store is not a criteria here, since all these apps are for in-house enterprise deployment.

Thanks!

Comment: You might look into the [built in data protection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html) features on iOS (scroll down a bit at that link) rather than reinventing the wheel. In an enterprise deployment you should be able to enforce a pass code requirement, which enables the built in encryption.

Comment: Er, missing the actual link... [here we go](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this, you'll need a jailbroken device.

There are the POSIX syscalls `read` and `write` which can be hijacked ([here's how](http://www.phrack.org/issues.html?issue=66&id=16) - not iOS-specific, but Darwin anyway...)

You can also use MobileSubstrate(http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileSubstrate) to hook the read() and write() functions in the C standard libraty which is almost exclusively used for the implementation of many basic frameworks and methods (including that of CocoaTouch - Foundation, CoreFoundation, and in fact some of the C and C++ standard libraries as well, etc.) - so most likely you won't need to alter the syscalls directly. Example:

```
static size_t (*orig_write)(int fd, void *buf, size_t n);

size_t hijacked_write(int fd, void *buf, size_t n)
{
    // do something, then
    return orig_write(fd, buf, n);
}

// in some initialization:
MSHookFunction(write, hijacked_write, (void **)&original_write);
```

Comment: Thanks. PS: I don't need to be jailbroken to do this. I can write the swizzling code myself and use it in my app. I just can't submit it to the app store.

Comment: @Karthik you **do** need to be JB'en. MSHookFunction requires kernel patches.

Comment: Sorry, just realized that we need to have a patched kernel since we need to do write our custom logic to a memory page which needs to be both writeable and executable; which the default kernel doesn't allow :(